# Is there a way to stabilize the 3D object on the Augmented Image

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, anchor, arcore

I'm setting up a scene and need my object to appear on one corner of the augmented image.

I've created a script to find the augmented image and set it as an anchor. domPrefab is instantiated on the anchors' position

```
            if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking && visualizer == null)
            {
                //First: detect the augmented image

                Anchor imageAnchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
                visualizer = Instantiate(AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab, imageAnchor.transform, imageAnchor);
                visualizer.Image = image;
                m_Visualizers.Add(image.DatabaseIndex, visualizer);

                //Second: Instantiate the prefabs

            GameObject prefab = domPrefab;
            var domObject = Instantiate(prefab, anchor.transform.position, anchor.transform.rotation);
            domObject.transform.Rotate(0, k_ModelRotation, 0, Space.Self);
            domObject.transform.SetParent(anchor.transform, true);
            }
```

I expect the domPrefab to be instantiated in the center of the augmented image, and when I will learn how to place it in the corner, then have the domPrefab appear in the corner of the image.

The actual result is: the domPrefab appear in the middle of the image but it's not stable. When camera looks around it moves a bit and its' scale changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating the anchor in the center of the image with this line

`Anchor imageAnchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);`

Then instantiate your visualizer at `imageAnchor` position and then try to rotate move or something but instead you can do this in your `AugmentedImageVisualizer`. To do this

1. Create an empty object and attach `AugmentedImageVisualizer` script to it.
2. Create a `public GameObject myModel` in `AugmentedImageVisualizer`
3. Put your model as a child to this object and drag it to `myModel` in inspector.
4. Create a prefab with this object
5. Modify your `AugmentedImageVisualizer` like this:

   ```
   public AugmentedImage Image;
   public GameObject myModel;

   public void Update()
   {

       float halfWidth = Image.ExtentX / 2;
       float halfHeight = Image.ExtentZ / 2;

       // for upper left
       myModel.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.left) + (halfHeight * Vector3.back);
       //for upper right
       myModel.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.right) + (halfHeight * Vector3.back);
       //for lower left
       myModel.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.left) + (halfHeight * Vector3.forward);
       //for lower right
       myModel.transform.localPosition = (halfWidth * Vector3.right) + (halfHeight * Vector3.forward);

   }
   ```
6. Use this as `AugmentedImageVisualizer` in your `AugmentedImageExampleController`

**If you want it to be stable and not change position over time, do the operation in fifth step in `Start` instead of `Update` or in another function and make sure it runs only once**.

I hope this helps Good Luck!

Comment: Just asking, if update is there to check image.CenterPose (continuously checking if model is on image.CenterPose), if image.CenterPose is checked only once at start, and if the model is misplaced on image at start, then model is never updated again.